# datatable shows "No data available in table"

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I have a child component which uses [angular datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome). This child table has **@Input() stockList: any[]**.

The problem I am facing is that even the datatable is loaded with data it always displays **"No data available in table"**

Despite of adding the following code in the child component:

```
<table id="parentTable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table row-border hover"
*ngIf="stockList">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        ......
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr #rowInstance *ngFor="let item of stockList; let i= index" (click)="toggleRow(i, item.id)">
       <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.color}}</td>
        ......
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dtTrigger.next();
}
```

It still gives the same issue. Am I missing any extra re-rendering and if yes, in which lifecycle event should I mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not put a `thead/tbody/tr(with ngIf)` inside your `table` element. The `dtOptions` configuration object contains the column label and the underlying property in JSON to be used for the column value. Try implementing it the way it has been demonstrated [here](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender) and check if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the description is not clear where is the child and where the parent tables.
Could you please provide more code. Parent html template, controller, child html template, child controller.